# installing a 700-18-23C tube on a bicycle

Tags: innertube, installation

When installing a 700-18/23C tube, does the nut on the valve stem go inside the tire (unseen once the tire is on the wheel rim) or outside the rim (so it is seen among the spokes)?

Comment: Remove the nut from the stem, install the tube, reinstall the nut.  Don't overtighten -- just get it snug.

Comment: it goes in the bin...

Answer (score 6):

It goes outside the rim, where you can see it.

It's not even strictly necessary. It really only exists to keep the valve stem in place while you air the tire up, which makes the whole process much easier. Weight weenies throw them away to save a couple grams.

Also note that if you use it, you don't want to screw it down too tight. Doing so can crimp your tube in the valve hole, causing it to puncture. Screw it on just enough to get the pump nozzle onto the valve. That's all you need. If airing the tire up exposes more of the valve, go ahead and screw it down until it just touches the rim.

PS: The tube size is actually irrelevant. The installation is the same for any tube with a [Presta valve](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/283/4239).

Comment: Those nuts are quite handy on Schraeder (sp?) valves as well.

Comment: @ChrisH I know they make Schraders with the threads all the way down like Prestas, but I've only ever seen them in pictures. Every one I've ever seen in real life has just enough threads for a cap.

Comment: I've just looked at the box for mine "Conti tour 28 (700C)" is what it says.  They're just what you get if you go to my LBS (L to work, that is) and ask for Schrader tubes, but they have the thread all the way down and a nut.  Makes pumping from empty much easier.

Comment: @ChrisH I wish I had your local bike shop. :)